# How to set out the background image of a jumbotron at full size and make it responsive?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, codepen

I want to make the background image of the jumbotron to have full size without needing to state the height in pixes. Reason for that is that I want it to be responsive. Also I want the image to be underneath the transparent navbar.

You can take a look [here](https://codepen.io/georgekech/pen/ZLNMGE)

The code for it is:

```
    <nav class="navbar-inner navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Cosmos</a>
    </div>
   <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="jumbotron" id="first">
      <h1 class="text-center" id="h1first">
        Welcome to Cosmos<br>
        web design
      </h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The css is:

```
    .navbar-inner {
    background:transparent;
}

#first {
  background-image: url(http://netdna.webdesignerdepot.com/uploads/2014/07/featured36.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  height: 900px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a min-height of `100vh` for your hero. And you have to position your navbar absolutely, like this:

https://codepen.io/Sixl/pen/oBrxKr

Comment: Still it's not the full size of the background image. The height is cut.

Comment: Yes, the image is set to 'cover' and we want it to be responsive. We don't know the actual viewport height and ratio, if landscape or portrait mode. The image will be cut off to adapt.

Comment: How can we set it as full image and then for it to get smaller and adopt according to the size of the window or the device? There is no way?

Comment: Exactly like this. Thank you, buddy. Don't delete the codepen please.

Comment: Then would you mind accepting the answer? :) Will keep the codepen open for your reference.